# How to convert timestamp to Milliseconds in Marketing cloud AMP scripts?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, datetime

We have field in salesforce which stores the current timestamp in milliseconds.We are updating values from MC to SC with default salesforce amp script functions.But there is no functions in AMP script to convert date to milliseconds.I know we can update through JS but since we are using salesforce amp script functions we need the solution in AMP script itself.

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use whatever date/time variable you are pulling, and then combine it with "FormatDate" ampscript:

https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/formatdate/

This should allow you to reach the desired format, including milliseconds

Comment: Thanks for your response.I have tried that and my code is %%=FormatDate(Now(), , "fff")=%%  but i dont think so its a correct value.This is the current time  6/30/2017 3:45:18 AM and its converted into 291 milliseconds.I need the output like from this site https://currentmillis.com/   example :1497615147094

Comment: Is it something you can help me on

Comment: That i do not believe is possible - if you take a look at the supported date/time formats, the format you are describing is not present: http://help.marketingcloud.com/globalassets/documentation/6725/dateformats_bylocale.txt

Comment: but - why do you need it in that format? would 6/30/2017 3:45:18 AM not be sufficient?

Comment: I don't know the purpose of this field but they want us pass the current time stamp to milliseconds

Comment: I think the closest you would be able to come is this format, using ampscript:
2010-01-13T14:15:16.0000000           I would suggest to try the support, asking if they have a way OR ask those who ask for it, why this is required?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61350/discussion-between-manoj-chandran-and-kenneth-wagner).